# OpenGL прозрачность текстуры на 3д модели

Tags: opengl, шейдеры, glsl, hlsl

Всем привет, проблема такая: имею 3D модель диска для колец Сатурна, на которую применяю текстуру с прозрачностью в разных местах.

Проблема в том, что прозрачный пиксель OpenGL, видимо, всё равно воспринимает, как пиксель, который что-то закрывает, поэтому прозрачные кольца Сатурна закрывают Солце, когда не должны.

Фрагментный шейдер для планетарных колец:

```
#version 460 core

uniform sampler2D unColorLookup;
uniform float unInnerRadius;
uniform float unOuterRadius;
uniform vec3 unLightPos;
uniform vec3 unPlanetPos;
uniform float unPlanetRadius;
uniform float unZCoef;

in vec3 fPosition;
in vec2 texCoords;
in vec3 fWorldPosition;
in float fLogZ;

void main() {
    gl_FragDepth = log2(fLogZ) * unZCoef * 0.5;
    float len = length(fPosition);
    float u = (len - unInnerRadius) / (unOuterRadius - unInnerRadius);

    if (abs(u) > 1.0) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0);
    } else {
        vec4 ringColor = texture(unColorLookup, texCoords);
        //const float smoothingAmount = 10.0;
        //float shadow = clamp(sphereIntersectAmount(normalize(fWorldPosition - unLightPos), fWorldPosition, unPlanetPos, unPlanetRadius) / smoothingAmount, 0.0, 1.0);
        //ringColor.rgb *= 1.0 - shadow;
        gl_FragColor = ringColor;
    }
}
```

Можно было бы с помощью `discard` отсекать полностью прозрачные пиксели, но это такое себе, потому что свет Солнца должен проходить даже сквозь полупрозрачные кольца и тд.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не ставь лишних тєгов. При чем здесь шарп, плюсы, питон, джава?

Comment: @Andrew, ну, может, потому что использовать API OpenGL можно, программируя на любом из этих языков? К тому же так больше увидит людей этот вопрос.
Я же всё равно в заголовке указываю, что вопрос связан с OpenGL, чтоб никто никого не запутать и т.д.

Comment: здесь не должно быть цели "как можно больше людей увидит", здесь должна быть цель поставить тэги правильно. Иначе в чем смысл если твой вопрос увидят люди которые вообще не отстреливают о чем здесь речь? Если вопрос про юнити - то используется HLSL язык. Не ставь все языки подряд. Никогда. А если хочешь больше внимания к вопросу - то задавай его на англоязычном SO. Но там тоже проставляй тэги правильно.

Comment: Как насчет классики? Сначала солнце, потом кольца с прозрачностью, потом блики камеры с прозрачностью? `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);  `